# How can I configure the tab width for TCL files

Tags: tabs

I set all `tab-width` parameters and indent parameters to 2, but Emacs always uses 8 for the tab space when I press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key at the beginning of a line, if i opened one bracket.

How can i set the tab for one bracket to 2 instead of 8?

Comment: `tab-width` is basically only relevant to how should Emacs *display* TAB characters.  What you need is to tweak the indentation parameters, so please tell us precisely what are those "indent parameters" you have "set to 2", since that's probably the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>M-x customize-variable</kbd> `tcl-indent-level`

`tab-width` is used by modes that are based on `c-mode`; `tcl-mode` is different, standalone.